# HTML turn a link into a button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="col-md-4 promo-item item-1">
    <h3>
      Unleash
    </h3>
  </div>
</a>
```

I got a template online, the above (with css/bootstrap?), is an image that is a link. I want to change it so that instead of a link (`href`), it's a clickable button.

My plan is for the button to use JavaScript to change some of the content on the page, basing it off the JavaScript below;

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='Hello JavaScript!' ">
  Click Me!
</button>
```

So how do I change this `href` into a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in bootstrap you just add the button classes and it will look like a button

```html
<a class='btn btn-default' ...
```

However, there is no reason you can't just copy the onclick attribute to the anchor tag (or "href" as you keep calling it).

---

From your code in the comments:

```html
<div id='demo'></div>

<a onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='Hello JavaScript!'; return false; "> Click Me!&gt; <div class="col-md-4 promo-item item-1"> <h3> Unleash </h3> </div> </a>
```

Comment: I dont want it to look like a button, I want it to be a clickable image that I can use to trigger javascript

Comment: Just for completeness, "look like a button" and "is a `<button>`" are not the same thing.

Comment: @NiallRedmond I totally not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @NiallRedmond please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @NiallRedmond - I updated the answer. just copy the onlick attribute to the `<a>`, it works exactly the same for both anchors and buttons.

Comment: Ok. Currently the code is a clickable image that is a link (href).
I want to change so that instead of being a link, it behaves like a button.

Comment: @NiallRedmond - did you do as i suggested? put the onclick attribute in the anchor?

Comment: @NiallRedmond So what's wrong with what you did so far?

Comment: @NiallRedmond Just attach a `click` listener on the image? Have you even tried that?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce I tried as you suggested;

 <a onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='Hello JavaScript!' ">
    Click Me!>
    <div class="col-md-4 promo-item item-1">
     <h3>
      Unleash
     </h3>
    </div>
            </a>

It did not work!

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 no. How do I do that?

Comment: Couple things.. return false to preevent the link from clickimg and you cant put > in html unless its part of a tag. Use &gt; instead

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. OK here's my onclick tag;

<a onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='Hello JavaScript!' ">


* have a body with id="demo"
How do I make it return false like you say?

Comment: @NiallRedmond - I fixed your code and put it in my answer. If that is what you needed please remember to click the check mark to select the answer. good luck :)

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Hmm not working. I have a question - what is 'document' ? is that supposed to be the name of the page? (mine is index.html)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That looks good if I can't get Iwrestled's way working i'll try that thanks

Comment: @NiallRedmond -  click on "run code snippet" it works fine. i explained exactly what the problem was. you cannot put the greater than symbol in raw html. you have to replace it with `&gt;`.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I copied your code exactly and it does not work on my html page. Any ideas why?

Comment: i can't say without seeing your code. it could be any number of things. something on your page is messed up. in that case derek's answer may not work either but give it a try. look in th console for errors. learn some basic javascript debugging .